# Display scrollbar for div according to media width

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am creating a table inside a tab. I want to set the width of tab to the width of media screen but keep the `width` of table fixed to `630px`. The `max-width` of div should be `400px`. When the table does not fit into the div, it should display a horizontal scrollbar.

The div is successfully showing a horizontal scrollbar. But, when I resize the window, the scrollbar along with table is hiding inside the div. I want to display the scrollbar according to media width.

The example will become clear:[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wzqhycy/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use tab and tab-content class width 100% may be it will work for you. I am sharing your complete code below with my changes i have done some width changes px to %, and what is the purpose for #model margin-right:1000px it will work find without margin.

```
#tabs-container {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-top: 10px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.tab {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
    background: linear-gradient(#f8fbea, #fff);
    margin: -20px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.tab-content {
    padding: 10px;
    width:100%
}

#model {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: -10px -10px -10px -320px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: tahoma;
}

#model {
    margin-right: 1000px;
    width: 630px;
}

#model td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#model tr:first-child td {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

#model tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

#model tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This worked but as you can see, the scrollbar is cropping a little from right side. What is the reason?

Comment: please remove margin from .tab{margin: -20px 10px 10px 10px;}, pleaes use 0 margin from left right.